# Appropriate test for checking signifigance in learning

Tags: bayesian, inference, p-value

I have conducted research as to if problem based learning is effective in language acquisition.
I have a set of 6 questions used in a pre and post test
There was a control group and a test group.
So for each question i have 4 sets of data taken from 2 groups of students, before and after intervention.
What test is appropriate for checking if the learning in the test group was more significant than the learning in the control group?
Must I run a separate test for each question?
How would I aggregate the data if there should be separate tests for each question in assessing significance in learning?